# acitivity_main.xml error: java.util.Locale.toLanguageTag()

Tags: java, android, android-activity

In the activity_main.xml page when i am trying to click on the imageview button and trying to bring it on the phone screen. it doesnt happen. moreover the phone screen has disappeared. I get the following error : java.util.Locale.toLanguageTag()Ljava/lang/String;

Comment: post a complete stack trace from logcat

Comment: i cannot add images because i have a reputation of 6 only. What should i do ? Please help !

Comment: why would you upload the logcat as image?

Comment: copy the text and post that.